# How to display Math Symbol in JLabel

Tags: java, math, symbols

I want to display like example 1e10 to 10^10 in JLabel, the ^10 become small size.

Comment: You can use HTML in a JLabel, and there's a <sup> tag to create superscript text. You could probably write some code to parse your text, and generate html that can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a label with x<sup>y</sup>:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel ("<html>x<sup>y</sup></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that just by using JLabel (assuming you don't want to put an image inside your JLabel).

Answer (score -1):

If it is really necessary you could write a custom Swing control... which would consist of several JLabels I guess.